# How to create buffer for custom source code region (e.g for each function)?

Tags: buffers, region, bookmarks, narrowing

Objective :
Frame some areas in a source code file, with custom pattern (e.g "# - Name of Region - #"),
and then having the choice to type the name of region to directly open a buffer containing only the region's inside text.

Could someone puts the name of something (plugin, function) that could help for this feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect)
([`narrow-indirect.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/narrow-indirect.el)) gives you an easy way to create an indirect buffer that is a clone of the current buffer and that is narrowed to a particular portion of it.

Library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) lets you bookmark regions, and it gives you an easy way to bookmark (persist) such a cloned narrowed buffer:

Command `bmkp-region-jump-narrow-indirect-other-window`:

> Jump to a region bookmark and narrow to it in a cloned indirect buffer.
> You are prompted for the region bookmark. The region is selected as usual, in the bookmarked file/buffer.  A separate window is opened on the region text, for the cloned indirect buffer.